# Import database from Excel

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a Web App for a inventory management.

The inventory is renewed every 4 months and it is in Excel.
My question or problem is, what or how could I do so that this inventory is updated automatically every 4 months or simply the customer can import the inventory manually through the Web App without having to modify the Excel sheet.

Is it possible to perform or automate such actions?

PD: Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: MySQL or MongoDB?

Comment: What do you suggest to use for this case? I have no problem using either.

Comment: *What do you suggest to use for this case?* I suggest select one of and remove excess tag. If needed then create another question with second tag only.

Comment: Done. With MySQL then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL.

Excel sheet data prepared for importing must be saved as CSV text file. This file must be placed in some place accessible by MySQL. These steps must be performed by some program/script/tool external to MySQL.

Then it must be imported using LOAD DATA INFILE statement into temporary table, imported data is processed and it either updates or replaces old data in working table(s). This steps can be performed from event procedure or executed malually (as separate queries or as solid stored procedure).